# How to roll back or uninstall Microsoft patch using WSUS?

Tags: wsus, rollback

Is it possible to use WSUS to roll back a patch? Specifically KB2501584?

Answer (score 8):

Approve the update - counterintuitive, eh? - for removal.

[image]

Comment: Ah! The famed intuitiveness of graphical user interfaces!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you should be able to, just choose the Update and choose the Remove option rather than Install. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720434(WS.10).aspx

However, I'm not sure if you will be able to do this based on the [KB description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464603)

> Note When you remove this security update, you may be prompted to insert the disc that contains Microsoft Office 2003. Additionally, you may not have the option of uninstalling this security update from the Add or Remove Programs item or from the Programs and Features item in Control Panel. There are several possible causes of this issue.

Comment: +1 for checking on whether this one could be successfully uninstalled - you'd think MS would have this down by now!